# Description of Symfony2 form events?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

This is the `FormEvents` class from Symfony2 repository on github. It's linked from the main article, [How to Dynamically Generate Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html).

***Anyone konws exactly when these events are called in the flow?***

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Form;

/**
 * @author Bernhard Schussek <bernhard.schussek@symfony.com>
 */
final class FormEvents
{
    const PRE_BIND = 'form.pre_bind';
    const POST_BIND = 'form.post_bind';
    const PRE_SET_DATA = 'form.pre_set_data';
    const POST_SET_DATA = 'form.post_set_data';
    const BIND_CLIENT_DATA = 'form.bind_client_data';
    const BIND_NORM_DATA = 'form.bind_norm_data';
    const SET_DATA = 'form.set_data';
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are two types of events:

[DataEvent](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Event/DataEvent.php) - read-only access to the form data. 'Pre' and 'Post' events are read-only.

[FilterDataEvent](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Event/FilterDataEvent.php) - event that allows the form data to be modified.

**form.pre_bind**
`DataEvent` triggered before data is bound to the form. Triggered by `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::bind()`

**form.post_bind**
`DataEvent` triggered after data is bound to the form. Triggered by `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::bind()`

**form.pre_set_data**
`DataEvent` triggered before fields are filled with default data. Triggered by `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::setData()`

**form.post_set_data**
`DataEvent` triggered after fields are filled with default data. Triggered by `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::setData()`

**form.bind_client_data**
`FilterDataEvent` triggered before data is bound to the form. Triggered by `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::bind()`

**form.bind_norm_data**
`FilterDataEvent` triggered after data has been normalized. Triggered by `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::bind()`. See `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\EventListener\FixUrlProtocolListener` (added by the `UrlType` for an example)

**form.set_data**
`FilterDataEvent` triggered while default data is being bound. Triggered by `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::setData()`

I'd recommend poking around the Form class itself to get a better feel for when these events are triggered, and how you can use them.

Comment: Really thank you, answer accepted! In the meanwhile i'm having some problems with form events, if you have some spare time maybe you can give me a little help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661026/accessing-a-form-field-from-a-subscriber-of-a-form-event-in-symfony2

Comment: It should be noted this description of the form events is only valid for Symfony 2.0 Form Component. The following events have been deprecated as of 2.1 and will be removed as of 2.3: `form.bind_client_data`, `form.bind_norm_data`, `form.set_data`. As of 2.1, form event listeners now receive a `FormEvent` object instead of the deprecated `FilterDataEvent` and `DataEvent` objects, which will be removed in 2.3.

Comment: Hey @xanido, your links are broken.

Comment: Links updated to point to 2.0 source (which as has been mentioned is the only version this answer really applies to). Thanks @Patt