# Accessing a form field from a subscriber (of a form event) in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm following the tutorial [How to Dynamically Generate Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html). I'm stuck on the creation of `AddNameFieldSubscriber`:

```
$subscriber = new AddNameFieldSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
```

My question is simple: how `FormFactory` can access and modify an arbitrary form field previously created by the `$builder`? And why we are passing the `FormFactory` instead of the `$builder` itself?

Assuming we have just two fields ("name" and "price") in the **builder**:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $subscriber = new AddProductTypeSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);

        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('price');
    }

    public function getName() { return 'product'; }
}
```

I'd like to set `required = false` (just an example) in the **subscriber**:

```
class ProductTypeSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(DataEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) return;

        // Access "name" field and set require = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong about it this, but I don't believe you can change a form's attributes after its been created. However, you can add to the form.

Instead of adding the 'name' field in `ProductType::buildForm`, you can defer this to the subscriber:

```
if (!$data->getId()) {
    $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('text', 'name', null, array('required' => false)));
} else {
    $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('text', 'name'));
}
```

Comment: That was also my fear. I will investigate further but i think exactely the same...

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?